# i have reactive form /dynamic form of attendance system for Employe in Angular.how i will generate json like this for backend

Tags: json, angular, typescript

i have reactive form /dynamic form of attendance system for Employe .when i click on submit ,i want to generate json like this.

```
{
  "user_id": "1", 
  "branch_id": "4", 
  "auth_token": "59a2a9337afb07255257199b03ed6076", 
  "date": "2019-11-12", 
  "attendance_log": [
    {
      "emp_id": "1", 
      "status": "Preset" 
    }, 
    {
      "emp_id": "1", 
      "status": "Preset" 
    },
    { 
      "emp_id": "1", 
      "status": "Preset" 
    }] 
}
```

and i want to pass json in backend to API.

how i will do?

Comment: In onsubmit event, pass formGroup value to api endpoint. `this.dataModel = this.formGroup.value;` here dataModel is your schema class. Using Angular's Http.post() you can send data to api.

Comment: but how it will convert to json formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- `form.value()` this will return only enabled control values.
- `form.getRawValue()` this will return JSON object for all of your controls enabled and as well disabled.

Then you can pass this JSON via post, hope that will solve your issue.